# Responsive design floating header, main and aside in 3 ways

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have a mobile-first approach with 3 containers that should fill the space in 3 different layouts as in the image below:

[image]

The closer I could get with CSS is this:

HTML:

```
<header>...</header>
<aside>...</aside>
<main>...</main>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header,
    main, 
    aside { width: 100%; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    main { float: left; width: 60%; }
    aside {float: right; width: 40%; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) {
    header: { float: left; width: 60%; }
}
```

Unfortunately, in the first layout aside will be right below the header instead of below the main. Could be really done in CSS? I'm open also for a JavaScript work-around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to re-arrange your HTML for the first layout. Here's a simple CSS solution for the 3 layouts.

```css
* {margin:0;}
header {
  background: #eee;
}
main {
  background: #ddd;
}
aside {
  background: #ccc;
}
header,main,aside {
  min-height: 100px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  main {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
  }
  aside {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  header, main {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
  aside {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<aside>aside</aside>
```

Comment: This seems to be the winner... absolute positioning. Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

you can use css3 media selector:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px) {
    ...
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    ...
}
```

[CSS3 @ media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Really? It's true that I used pseudo-code but I thought that is understood that means media queries. I will edit my question though in order to avoid the misunderstanding.